# Woraus leitet sich "jemandem/etwas nachstellen" ab?

Tags: etymology

Das Wort "jemandem/etwas nachstellen" bedeutet meines Wissens "jemanden/etwas verfolgen".

Was ist die Herkunft dieses Worts? Der einzige vage Hinweis, den ich finden konnte, ist ein Halbsatz in [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nachstellen):

> vom Fallenstellen des Jägers gesagt

Ich finde die Formulierung eher merkwürdig (was soll "vom ... gesagt" bedeuten? "Es wird gesagt, dass das Wort vom ... abgeleitet ist."? Warum steht das da nicht?), aber dass "nachstellen" mit "Fallenstellen" zu tun hat, könnte durchaus sein - gibt es dafür oder für andere Erklärungen weitere Belege?

Das einzige potenziell mit "nachstellen" verwandte Wort, in dem das Konzept des Jagens mitschwingt, das mir einfällt, scheint "jemanden/etwas stellen" (im Sinn von "fangen") zu sein.

Comment: Hier fällt wenigstens ein Vergleich zu *stelzen*, vielleicht auch *nachahmen* (viz. acc. *jnd. nachstellen*, vgl. *Lockvogel*, En. *stool bird*?), daher vielleicht auch *Stelzbock* (aka Holzbock? s. auch *Gestell*, *Tor (vom Rind)*). s. ferner Engl. *nook*.

Answer (score 4):

Der [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GN01131#XGN01131) weiss sinngemäß dasselbe:

> intransitiv (doch nur scheinbar, weil das object falle, netz und dgl. verschwiegen ist), zunächst vom vogelsteller und jäger, der die fallen, schlingen, netze nach einem vogel oder wilde stellt, sodann übertragen: nachtrachten, zu erreichen suchen in guter oder feindlicher absicht; mhd. stellen nâch nur mit präpositionaler fügung, die auch heute neben der adverbialen fortdauert, aber noch den persönlichen dativ erfordert: er stellt meinem leben nach oder er stellt mir nach dem leben; mhd. der stellet nâch zerganclîchen dingen. Grieshaber pred. 2, 32; nâch êren stellen. mystiker 1, 312, 26; nhd.
> und die uns stellen nach unsern weiben. fastn. sp. 620, 31. 710, 18;

und er erwähnt auch einen "listigen" Unterton:

> nach eerenämpteren stellen. Maaler 299d; nach gut, nach eren, nach gunst, nach freiheit stellen. Aler 1437b; er stellet ihm nach leib und leben. ebenda. vgl. DWB nachstehen.
> A. mit dem nebenbegriff des feindlichen, listigen oder heimlichen: eine falle oder schlinge legen, ein netz stellen um darin zu fangen, dann überhaupt listig zu erreichen, zu fangen, in seinen besitz, in seine gewalt zu bekommen oder zu tödten suchen, feindlich nachtrachten, auflauern, verfolgen.
> a) mit dem dativ eines lebenden wesens.
> α) dem wild nachstellen. Kramer 2, 151b; kein wild, dem er nachstalt, mocht im entgehen. Carron schlangenb. 37a;

Comment: Ah ja, stimmt. Der Grimm ist natürlich auch eine erste Adresse :-)

Comment: Falls es *nach* ~ En. *nook*--was soweit eine reine Behauptung meinerseits ist--wäre es falsch zu behaupten, dass "das object falle, netz und dgl. verschwiegen ist".

Answer (score 2):

Die erste Adresse für etymologische Fragen des Deutschen ist

Wolfgang Pfeifer: **Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Deutschen**, Akademie-Verlag Berlin 1989.

Glücklicherweise ist die zweite Auflage von 1993 online verfügbar, im Digitalen Wörterbuch der Deutschen Sprache, dwds.de

Dort findet man unter [**stellen**](https://www.dwds.de/wb/nachstellen#et-1):

> **nachstellen** Vb. ‘auflauern, verfolgen’ (16. Jh.; eigentlich Schlingen, Fallen stellen).

Das passt also sehr gut zu deinem Beleg im Duden. *Einem Wild nachstellen* heißt also, *einem Wild eine Falle stellen*

Comment: Ich dachte die erste Adresse sei der Kluge (sic!).

Comment: Nein, der Pfeifer ist viel besser - es gibt mehr Lemmata und die Einträge sind deutlich detaillierter.

Comment: Euch wird aufgefallen sein, dass außer eines post quem Datums keinerlei etymologische Information dabei steht. Was daran detailiert sein soll weiß der Geier. Kluge/Seebold dafür in Abrede zu stellen gehte mal gar nicht. Der ist allenfalls nachrangig weil nicht frei im Netz verfügbar. Ggf. steht da ja mehr, das wäre hier noch beizubringen, wenngleich zu erwarten steht, dass beide Bücher von Grimm abkupfert haben.